# anyway to make this code smaller?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search-indexing

I have created a formula which index matches from different work sheets and then adds them together.

**Is there anyway possible to make the coding smaller or better?**
I have tried and failed, but getting no results :(

.

I have the following code;

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Report 1'!BC:BC,MATCH(B13,'Report 1'!$A:$A,0)),"0")
+IFERROR(INDEX('Report 2'!BC:BC,MATCH(B13,'Report 2'!$A:$A,0)),"0")
+IFERROR(INDEX('Report 3'!BC:BC,MATCH(B13,'Report 3'!$A:$A,0)),"0")
+IFERROR(INDEX('Report 4'!BC:BC,MATCH(B13,'Report 4'!$A:$A,0)),"0")
+IFERROR(INDEX('Report 5'!BC:BC,MATCH(B13,'Report 5'!$A:$A,0)),"0")
```

Answer (score 1):

To get results from your formula remove the `"` from around the `0` so the formula is not trying to add text strings.

but we can shorten the formula with a [3D SUMIF](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-3d-sumif-across-multiple-worksheets)

With the names of the desired sheets in a list and references them with INDIRECT in a SUMIF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & D1:D5 & "'!A:A"),B13,INDIRECT("'" & D1:D5 & "'!BC:BC")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway possible to make the coding smaller or better?

Not really:(

Although you can use some workarounds:

- [named range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64): you can define names for your ranges and refer to them
- support cell: use another cell to store the result of your `MATCH` function, so don't need to run it multiple times
- UDF: use a macro to create user defined function where you can write nicer code than your current formula